# Issue with ActionMailer Mandrill in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, mandrill

I have a cab booking platform created in Rails. I am using the Mandrill smtp settings in production to send booking confirmation mails to users of my platform. Then I generated a mailer called user_mailer with the following code:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "my_company_email"
  def booking_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Booking Confirmation")
  end
end
```

Then I created booking_confirmation.html.erb page in user_mailer views with some generic content inside. Finally I called the user_mailer in one of my controllers as follows:

```
UserMailer.booking_confirmation(current_user).deliver
```

My problem is that when I want to include more details (such as Travel date, Travel time, etc.) within the mail delivered to my customer. I am trying this within my booking_confirmation.html.erb page: `<%= @user.bookings.last.date %>` to display the Travel Date to the customer. But this doesn't get displayed. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass in the booking like 
`UserMailer.booking_confirmation(current_user, booking.id).deliver`

then in the `class UserMailer` I would do

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "my_company_email"
  def booking_confirmation(user, booking)
    @user = user
    @booking = Booking.find(booking)
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Booking Confirmation")
  end
end
```

now on your erb you should have  `@booking.date` to use

Answer (score 1):

Its not a mandrill issue.something wrong with application code.
Check whether your following code has the date value present for last bookings.

> @user.bookings.last.date